# Htaccess interpret query string as directory into a script

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, apache, .htaccess

I have the structure of url http://192.168.0.10/college/baseball/player.

"player" is a php file.
"stadium/baseball" are directories.
This works fine with a htaccess.

I use a query string like this on 123 is a id of the player
http://192.168.0.10/college/baseball/player/123
The htaccess inteprets to player.php?id=123
This works fine too

The problem is when I use a ajax call or include another php file into a URL "player/123" the serve interprets is a directory, not a file into a "baseball" directory.

This is a htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([A-z]+)\/?$ $1.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/([A-Za-z0-9]+)\/?$ $1.php?k=$2 [NC]
```

> Warning: include(sector/456): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in